# c - static 2d array of pointers to 2d arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Is it possible to create statically in C a 2d array of pointers to 2d arrays, like:

```
#define m 4
#define n 4
#define p 2
#define q 2

char arr1[m][n] = {{0}};
char arr2[m][n] = {{0}};
char (*parr[m][n])[p][q] = {{&arr1, 0, &arr2, 0}};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

The 2d array of pointers `parr` is sparse, with some values to 0 (NULL), which is why I don't want to use a 4d array in the first place.

This compiles, but I get the following warning:

> warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type

With the following command:

> gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 test.c

What is wrong?

Comment: Please post the actual code you are having problems with. I cannot reproduce the compiler warning and your code looks fine (apart from a1 needing to be arr1). One possible cause could be that NULL is not defined to be 0 on your particular compiler. Try to change the 0 in the 2D array to NULL. Also if possible, consider using a typedef for the array type so that the code gets easier to read.

Comment: I updated my post with a full working example and the GCC command line I use.

Comment: @Lundin Same warning when I use NULL instead of 0 (including stddef.h).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you declare pointers, arrays and array pointers, the [] takes precedence over * unless you add parenthesis. This is why you declare an array pointer as `(*parr)[]` rather than `*parr[]`, since the latter gives an array of pointers instead.

Similarly, when declaring a pointer to a 2D array, you would type `(*parr)[m][n]`. So it seems logical that an array of 2D-array pointers should be declared as `((*parr)[m][n])[p][q])`. But the outer parenthesis here actually does nothing, that expression is equivalent to `(*parr)[m][n][p][q]`. And that's an array pointer to a 4D array! Which is why you get compiler warnings.

Now what you actually want is to get an array of array pointers to 2D arrays, is something like `char (*parr[p][q])[m][n]`. Which looks rather insane, nobody will understand a declaration like that.

The only sane way to write code like this is through typedefs:

```
typedef char arr_t[m][n];

arr_t arr1 = {{0}};  
arr_t arr2 = {{0}};  
arr_t* parr[p][q] =
{
  {&arr1, 0},
  {&arr2, 0}
};
```

Comment: Best looking solution so far, but my printf show incorrect result -- are you sure it works?

Comment: @susundberg You need to feed something like `(*parr[0][0])[0][0]` to printf for it to work.

Comment: That seems correct, thanks for correction, using "printf("%d", (int)((*parr[0][0])[i][j] - (*parr[1][0])[i][j] ) );" the answear works fine!

Comment: "*The only sane way to write code like this ...*" isn't it the "*only*" **possible** way to do so? As per the parenthis-language-quirk you mention as "*But the outer parenthesis here actually do nothing ...*"?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you meant to do is the following:

```
char arr1[m][n] = {{0}};
char arr2[m][n] = {{0}};

typedef char (*some_type)[n];  // type of arr1 and arr2
some_type parr[p][q] = {{arr1, NULL}, {arr2, NULL}};  //array containing arr1 and arr2
```

You can then access `parr` e.g by

```
printf("%c\n", parr[0][0][0][0]);
```

which will print `arr1[0][0]`.

Answer (score 1):

In the declaration of *parr* I think you meant to use *p* and *q* as its dimensions:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

#define m 4
#define n 4
#define p 2
#define q 2

char arr1[m][n] = {{0}};
char arr2[m][n] = {{0}};

char (*parr[p][q])[m][n] = {{&arr1, NULL}, {&arr2, NULL}};

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", (*parr[0][0])[0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles cleanly with GCC 4.8.2:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
$ gcc -ansi -fsanitize=address -g -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wfatal-errors -Wno-unused-parameter -o test test.c
$
```

Comment: Are you sure this works, i got some weird results when trying to run this, more precise `silly2.c:27:54: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
             printf("%d,%d ", (char)parr[0][0][i][j], (char)parr[1][0][i][j] );
`

Comment: I believe the printf should be `parr[0][0][0][0]`.

Comment: Doing printf, like on my answear, but in 2d array fashion, gives also weird results -- actually the sames as @Lundin gives, -16 on every cell, its not only the warning that buggers me.

Comment: @susundberg You need to dereference the pointer to the second matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Here would be my solution -- i prefer using static 1D arrays rather than static 2D arrays due pointer arithmetic (i like to keep things simple):

PS. i would suggestin using m!=n and p!=q for testing, so you can catch possible indexing errors!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define m 4
#define n 4
#define p 2
#define q 2


char arr1[m*n] = {0};
char arr2[m*n] = {0};
typedef char array_2d[m][n];

char* parr[p][q] = { {(char*)arr1, NULL}, { (char*)arr2, NULL} };


int main() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i ++ )
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j ++ )
    {
       arr1[i*n + j] = i + j;
       arr2[i*n + j] = i - j;
    }

     for (int i = 0; i < m; i ++ )
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < n; j ++ )
         {
            char* arr1_ptr = parr[0][0];
            char* arr2_ptr = parr[1][0];
            printf("%d", (int)(arr1_ptr[i*n + j] - arr2_ptr[i*n + j] ));
         }
         printf("\n");
     }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem with "mangled" arrays is that you have to calculate the dimensions in runtime, which adds extra overhead code. And the code gets a bit harder to read.

Comment: Based on my tests 2D static arrays are 1D arrays like this after compiler does its magic, so i think this is less mangled code than with 2D arrays. About the 'ease of reading' : do you prefer extra "typedef + (*parr[0][1])[i][j]" or just "parr[0][1][i*n + j]". I go with later.

Comment: Neither is good. If I ever found myself needing a 2D array of array pointers, I'd take a step back and try to find out where my fundamental program design went wrong.